# Linking to winmm.dll from GCC

Tags: c, gcc, dll, linker

I would like to use mciSendString from gcc to build a dll so I need to link to the winmm.dll library.

I tried something like this:

```
gcc -c -o dllTest.o dllTest.c -lC:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll
```

But when i tried to build the dll I get an undefined reference for mciSendString.

What is the proper way to link to winmm from gcc?

Comment: You use mingw then you link to c:\mingw\lib\libwinmm.a

Comment: try `gcc -o dllTest dllTest.c C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll`, `-c` not linking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the end I was able to get it to work with -lwinmm instead of the big path to the library.