# How to use PlaySound in C

Tags: c, audio, codeblocks, wav, winmm

I am using code::blocks IDE which runs on GNU GCC compiler. In my project I want to play a **.wav** sound file in C. I tried to play a **.wav** sound file with a function called *PlaySound*. When I compiled the code code::blocks gave me an error - PlaySoundA not declared. My code is-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  PlaySound("C:\Snakes and Ladders\snake.wav",NULL,SND_SYNC | SND_LOOP | SND_FILENAME);
  return 0;
}
```

I checked my path twice. I read about this function on the internet and as per me I am using it in the correct way.

In Google, I read that the function exists in a file called **winmm.lib**. So I put a line of code after all the headers. It was-

```
 #pragma comment (lib , "winmm.lib")
```

I also added the name winmm.lib to the additional dependencies of code::blocks. So now when I compile the code it gives me another error - winmm.lib not found. Can somebody please tell me how to use PlaySound correctly.

Comment: Replace \ with \\ in your path.  like `C:\\Snakes and Ladders\\snake.wav`

Comment: code::blocks gives me error if I put **Mmsystem.h** that is why I put **mmsystem.h**.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2008, and in this is working fine.

Comment: You are using gcc, don't mix this with msvc things like that pragma. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837556/linking-to-winmm-dll-from-gcc

Comment: Himanshu, you are using visual studio 2008, not code::blocks. If you want to see it yourself, download code::blocks and try putting **Mmsystem.h**. It will not work.

Comment: Have you linked winmm.lib to your script (with the `-lwinmm` flag)?

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove the pragma comment
2. Double the backslashes. The backslash is an escape character
3. Compile with the winmm library. Using MinGW, the command would look like this:

   gcc foo.c -o foo.exe -lwinmm

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings - compiler... - linker settings. on the right side in other linker option write this:-lwinmm