# Playing sound using MinGW

Tags: c++, audio, mingw

I want to play sounds in my application using mciSendString. For this purpose I found the following simple snippet on the Microsoft website:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Winmm.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  mciSendString("play MyFile wait", NULL, 0, 0);
  mciSendString("close MyFile", NULL, 0, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

My problem is that I don't use Visual Studio. Is there a way to get this example compiled via MinGW?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking to winmm.dll from GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837556/linking-to-winmm-dll-from-gcc)

Comment: The post describes how to link the dll but not how to compile, where I can find the headers and lib etc.

Comment: You don't need the `lib` file to compile. The header is just `windows.h` (which includes `winmm.h`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I remove the MSVS-isms

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
  mciSendString("play MyFile wait", NULL, 0, 0);
  mciSendString("close MyFile", NULL, 0, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

and compile with

```
g++ -o test.exe "src\\test.o" -lwinmm
```

[as per the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837556/linking-to-winmm-dll-from-gcc), the build is successful.